# Get Intel Network Interface Card Supported RSS Descriptor Queue Number

Tags: networking, intel, centos5, nic, network-interface

Is there a way to get the supported number of Receive-Side Scaling descriptor queues for a Intel Network Interface Card in Centos5 programmatically?

For example for `I210` I want to get `4`, for `I350` I want to get `8`.

I will use that value on `modprobe.conf` file to pass RSS parameter to igb module. For example: `options igb RSS=4,8`

I tried `lspci -vvv` and `ethtool -i interface` but none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research, I found out it is enough to assign `0` to all RSS parameters of igb module. It automatically assigns minimum of cpu number or queue number. For example: `options igb RSS=0,0`

From README file of igb driver:

```
0 = Assign up to the lesser value of the number of CPUs or the number of queues
```